# How to get day from a date in excel, if date isn't in date format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have text written like this "2015.05.24". When I right click on the cell and go "format cell", I found out that it's "general" and not date.

I try to get the day with =text(a1,"ddd") which normally works for me, but here it doesn't.

I tried to select custom format and type in "yyyy.m.d" but it doesn't work. So is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number format does not change the underlying data it only masks it if it is a number.

You can use:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","-"),"ddd")
```

By replacing the `.` with `-` we create a format of a date that Excel can parse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, use:

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),RIGHT(A1,2)),"ddd")
```

[image]